# NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run this code below. It was working previously, but when I added a second datareader, it stopped. Can anyone tell me what's wrong ?

```
Protected Sub btnSearchUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchUser.Click

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim searchComm As String = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE @username"
        Dim user_id_select As New Integer

        Dim searchSQL As New SqlCommand

        conn.Open()

        searchSQL = New SqlCommand(searchComm, conn)
        searchSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserSearch.Text)

        Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = searchSQL.ExecuteReader()

        While datareader.Read

            lstUsers.Items.Add(datareader.Item("username"))

        End While

        datareader.Close()
        conn.Close()


        Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim selectComm As String = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=@username_selected"

        Dim selectSQL As New SqlCommand

        conn2.Open()


        selectSQL = New SqlCommand(selectComm, conn2)
        selectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username_selected", lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text.Trim)

        Dim datareader2 As SqlDataReader = selectSQL.ExecuteReader()

        While datareader2.Read

            If datareader2.HasRows Then

                user_id_select = datareader2("user_id")

                lblUserSelected.Text = "Selected: " + lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text

            ElseIf datareader2.HasRows = False Then

                lblInvalidUsername.Visible = True
                datareader2.Close()


            End If

        End While


        conn2.Close()



    End Sub
```

[image]

Hi,

I'm gettin a NullReference exception on `lblUserSelected.Text = "Selected: " + lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text` whenever I enter a username in `txtUserSearch` and click search, it was working previously.. I don't know what happened..

Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Probably the `lstUsers` is the null, and is hide from something that you do now have here.

Comment: Does `lstUsers` even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're getting the `NullReferenceException` on this line:

```
selectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username_selected", lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text.Trim)
```

since you haven't specified the `SelectedItem` of the recently filled `ListBox`. To select the first item you could use this code:

```
While datareader.Read
    lstUsers.Items.Add(datareader.Item("username"))
End While
If lstUsers.Items.Count <> 0 Then lstUsers.SelectedIndex = 0
```

You are also not handling the case that there are no usernames in the database, then the `ListBox` is empty and has no selected-item.